# How To Create Reusable Component in ASP.NET Core with Javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

Since moving to MVC I have always wondered (and now am in need of) a reusable "component" that I can stick on any view that does something that is common to every view and include jQuery within that component.  I'm talking about View Components and they are neat, but I have yet to come across a viable need for them (other than displaying an address or phone number).  Nothing really interactive.

So, if I can't do this with a View Component, what do I do? I have a View Component that utilizes JavaScript, but that's only because I couldn't reference the section that I defined in my Layout.  I've read dozens of articles that state that this is by design.  Well, in my opinion, this is a poor design and locks these components to be non-interactive (or limited).

Comment: I would add a Scoped Service `MyViewContext` into the Dependency Injection Container, which will let you share some elements. If you need it, simple inject it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have always wondered (and now am in need of) a reusable "component" that I can stick on any view

I think what you are looking for is [templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html).  It's reusable in that models can have display and editor templates.  It's pretty much as simple as:

Reusable:

```
public class Car
{
  public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

Controller model:

```
public class IndexVM
{
  public Car Car { get; set; }
}
```

index.cshtml

```
@model IndexVm

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Car)
```

shared/displaytemplates/car.cshtml

```
@model Car

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Model)
```

As for scripts, the idea of rendering only the JS needed died a long time ago.  It's why Bootstrap has bootstrap.min.js, bootstrap.min.css.  There isn't a good reason to not *bundle* everything together so the client can cache it all-at-once.

View Components I feel are kinda hacky in MVC.  They are sort of this catch all that *works* in MVC and WebPages but wasn't really thought out.

[More Reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms)

Comment: I agree with your thoughts on View Components. I never thought about using a template. I am currently using editor templates for other models, so no reason why I can't apply the same concept for a "component" on any view. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1):

Create a service:

```
public class MyViewContext
{
    public bool IsJqueryRequired { get; set; }
    public object MyAwesomeSharedObject { get; set; }
}
```

Then add it to the DI Container scoped (Scoped is created every new Request):

```
services.AddScoped<MyViewContext, MyViewContext>();
```

In your view you can access it this way:

```
@inject MyViewContext MyViewContext
```

Every where else by simple using [constructor injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection).

Another great option is using TagHelper and the `TagHelperContext`. [Here](https://scottaddie.com/2017/01/30/building-complex-ui-components-with-asp-net-core-mvc-tag-helpers/) is an great article about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Christian. The concept of using constructor injection actually makes a lot of sense and I might have to give it a go and see if I like the result.